# Execution default of goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile failed: Unable to load the mojo 'compile'

Tags: eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

I try to add `org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1` into my springboot application `pom.xml` to generate automaticly protobuff java code when I use Maven Update Project.

[image: ERROR]

The error appear sometime. If I use "Maven Update Project" and "Project > Clean ...", it will disappear sometime. However, it still there which I can't tolerate anymore.

The error I meet:

```
Execution default of goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile failed: Unable to load the mojo 'compile' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1' (org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile:default:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile failed: Unable to load the mojo 'compile' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$7(MavenImpl.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: Unable to load the mojo 'compile' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:553)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
  roleHint: org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 33 more
```

The `<build>` of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kr.motd.maven/os-maven-plugin -->
          <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>initialize</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>detect</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/index.html -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xolstice.maven.plugins/protobuf-maven-plugin -->
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                  <!--  <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobuf.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact> -->
                <!-- https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html -->
                <!-- 默认为: src/main/proto/xxx.proto -->
                <!-- <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/proto</protoSourceRoot> -->
                <!-- 默认为: ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/protobuf/java，会自动添加为source，因为使用默认即可 -->
                <!-- <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory> -->
                <!-- 当 clearOutputDirectory = true 时，每次执行都会清楚 outputDirectory 指定的目录下的所有文件 -->
                <!-- <clearOutputDirectory>false</clearOutputDirectory> -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The error happens in :

```xml
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```